# Subpages not showing up as children in mainnavigation (Typo3)

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have several pages with subpages in my pagetree as shown below.

[My pagetree with subpages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euygw.png)

However, the links to the subpages do not seem to be clickable.

I have implemented my navigation in Fluid, as per the code below (which is in the default.html file in the Layouts folder):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{rl}">Company Name</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <f:for each="{mainnavigation}" as="mainnavigationItem">
                <f:if condition="{mainnavigationItem.children}">
                    <f:then>
                        <li class="nav-item {f:if(condition: mainnavigationItem.active, then:'active')} dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                {mainnavigationItem.title}
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <f:for each="{mainnavigationItem.children}" as="child">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{child.link}" target="{child.target}" title="{child.title}">{child.title}</a>
                                </f:for>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </f:then>
                    <f:else>
                        <li class="nav-item {f:if(condition: mainnavigationItem.active, then:'active')}">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{mainnavigationItem.link}" target="{mainnavigationItem.target}" title="{mainnavigationItem.title}">{mainnavigationItem.title} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </f:else>
                </f:if>
            </f:for>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And the mainnavigation variable is defined in the configuration of my extension in setup.typoscript as shown below. Note that levels is set to 2, in order to render the subpages.

```
  dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
            10 {
                references.fieldName = media
            }
            20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
            20 {
                levels = 2
                includeSpacer = 1
                as = mainnavigation
            }
        }
```

As you can see in the picture below, an arrow is added for the subpages. When I click this arrow or the page title, nothing happens however.

[The menu with dropdowns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrl7w.png)

Additionally I am getting this error in the webconsole:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
at util.js:55
at bootstrap.min.js:6
at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

Which refers to:

```
$.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = transitionEndEmulator
```

Comment: Can you add your setup of your navigation (MenuProcessor or however you implemented)?

Comment: I have added my implementation of the menu!

Comment: I meant, if you can add your code to your question here :-)

Comment: @MikelWohlschlegel I have added it to the question here, it's written in fluid. Or did you want to see another piece of the code?

Comment: Fluid is just the way of rendering the frontend. You render a variable called $mainnavigation in a for loop of your template. This var is not defined within the fluid template, but somewhere in your TypoScript setup (it looks like a MenuProcessor). Can you post the definition of $mainnavigation here? (Take a look into your TS-Setup --> PAGE)

Comment: @MikelWohlschlegel It looks like mainnavigation is defined in multiple setup.typoscript files of different extensions, so I added the one I found in the bootstrap extension. Let me know if this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was not importing JQuery correctly in setup.typoscript. Once I added the following code to page, the subpages popped up correctly:

```
 includeJSFooter {
   jquery = https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
   jquery.external = 1
   popper = https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js
   popper.external = 1
   bootstrap = https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
   bootstrap.external = 1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at your Setup – there you are able to define the navigation, see also [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/CreateAMenu/Index.html)

Comment: As far as I understand my Setup of the navigation should include the subpages, so I still do not understand why they aren't showing up. Also I'm using fluid instead of typoscript for the navigation.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you create a new menu in your Setup with a not used variable-name like "testnavigation" (so you have complete control over this variable). And then you could try to use this example: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/MainMenuCreation/Index.html
And do not forget to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your html code.

Your code:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{child.link}" target="{child.target}" title="{child.title}>{child.title}</a>
```

Should be:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{child.link}" target="{child.target}" title="{child.title}">{child.title}</a>
```

Missing **"** after {child.title}, so the  is not closed correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Ive managed to get the arrows for the dropdown to show now, but the dropdown menus itself are not showing up when I press the link